# Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to 'System.DateTime'

Tags: powershell

I'm attempting to write a script that will compare the dates of two versions of the same file, and copy it across if appropriate.

Being new to Powershell, I am just attempting to figure out the correct syntax to get this working, however I've run into a glitch, and I'm not sure what is happening or why.

```
$RemotePath = "e:\to be copied"
$LocalPath = "C:\temp"
$Curr_date = get-date

#Checking date and then copying file from RemotePath to LocalPath
Foreach($file in (Get-ChildItem $RemotePath))
{
    #Check if file exists. If it doesn't, copy the file.
    if (-Not (Test-Path "$LocalPath\$file"))
    {
        echo "$LocalPath\$file"
        "$file does not exist"
    }
    else
    {
        $LocalFile = (Get-ChildItem $LocalPath)
        echo $LocalFile
        echo $LocalFile.LastWriteTime
        echo $file
        echo $file.LastWriteTime
        #Check if newer (greater) than date of file in the Local Path
        if((get-date $file.LastWriteTime) -gt (get-date $LocalFile.LastWriteTime))
        {
            echo $Curr_date
            echo $file.LastWriteTime
            echo $LocalFile.LastWriteTime
        }
        #If not newer, don't copy file.
        else
        {
            echo $Curr_date
            echo $file.LastWriteTime
            echo $LocalFile.LastWriteTime
            "not copying $file"
        }
    }
}
```

I *believe* it's caused by the line:

```
if((get-date $file.LastWriteTime) -gt (get-date $LocalFile.LastWriteTime))
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Get-Date : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.DateTime' required by parameter 'Date'. Specified method is not supported.
At C:\Users\Benjamin\Desktop\PowerShell.ps1:24 char:57
+         if((get-date $file.LastWriteTime) -gt (get-date $LocalFile.LastWriteTime ...
+                                                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-Date], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgument,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetDateCommand
```

Additionally, this echo's the data for the files in `C:\temp`, then one file in `E:\To be copied`, then throws the error. It then loops again, echo's the files in `C:\temp`, then the *other* file in `E:\To be copied`, then throws the error again.

Comment: Why are you using Get-Date to get the date(time) out of a property that is already a datetime?  You should be able to just compare the properties.  I suspect that the problem is that $file or $localfile is not a single file (for some reason).

Comment: Most likely. There are 2 files in each directory, so if that's a problem I'll look into a better way to code this. As for the `get-date` issue, I'm not really fluent in powershell syntax, so the choice of syntax was ill informed

Comment: If the properties were strings, your syntax would have been fine.  It's just redundant if they're already datetimes.

Answer (score 1):

The error begins here:

```
$LocalFile = (Get-ChildItem $LocalPath)
```

Calling `Get-ChildItem` on your current path returns every child... an array. Next, as part of the `if` statement, you'll do this:

```
$LocalFile.LastWriteTime
```

That's still an array. You're now trying to pass an `Object[]` to the `Get-Date` commandlet, and it doesn't know what to do with it.

Comment: So should I make that `if` statement inside a `foreach`?

Comment: Run the commands one at a time, piped to Get-Member.  For example, `$LocalFile.LastWriteTime | GM` to see what objects are returned.